# PHP export MySQL to csv for app inventor

Tags: php, mysql, csv, app-inventor

When I try to export MySQL table to csv (use php) and make it a list in app inventor, but the list doesn't show.

**My Block :**
[image]

**My php file :**

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SHOW COLOMNS FROM Absent")){

$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
if($numberOfRows > 0) {
$values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT full_name FROM Absent");
while($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)){
for($j=0; $j<$numberOfRows; $j++) {
$csv_output .=$rowr [$j]. " ,";
}
$csv_output .= "\n";
}
}
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know much about app-inventor, but as for the sql queries:

- the first table is "CUSTOMER", your second is: "Absent", is it a typo?
  (your'e iterating your "Absent" row with the number of columns you're getting from "CUSTOMER", was that your intention?)
- your "$rowr" var has only 1 column ("full_name"), so you could easily:
  drop the "for loop", to:

  $csv_output .=$rowr [0];

P.S.
an alternative way of coding that in php would be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM Absent");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $comma = "";
   foreach(  $row as $key=>$value )
   {
       $csv_output .= $comma . $value;
       $comma = ", ";
   }
   $csv_output .= "\n";
}

print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Comment: And the 'output' will be csv row or csv table?

Comment: each line in "$csv_output" represents a single row in "Absent" table. of course, "$csv_output" is a string param. .

Comment: Okay that work, but the list still doesn't  show in the app :(

Comment: seems like your app needs a specified format for the list to be load. so i suggest you give a "fake" input to: "$csv_output", say: `$csv_output = "value1\nvalue2\nvalue3"`.  when you get a fake output that works, compare it to the output you get from the "while statement"

Comment: Not Effect anything... I think the app can't show the csv file from internet. I think the $csv_output must downloaded first at tmp directory and the app load the file from storange

Comment: Hey... Look this is the output [link](http://www.superstudents7.com/test/host/absendigital/daftarnama.php)

Comment: i see you get empty and duplicate values, maybe that's your problem? . make these changes to avoid them, and tell me if that helps: 1. change your query to: `SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM Absent WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL AND column1 <>"";` . 2. add this line in the beginning of the "foreach" block: `if ( empty($value) ) continue; `.

Answer (score 1):

Try to export to csv using mysql native method, for example:

```
SELECT id, name, email INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY ‘\\’
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM users WHERE 1
```